# Insert Rows based on Missing numbers in repeated Series using Excel or Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with the following format (actually, the repeat number is larger than 4):

```
Number, Time, Speed
1, 12, 5.8
2, 11, 6.2
3, 9, 7.0
4, 3, 11.9
1, 6, 9.5
3, 7.5, 8.2
4, 4.2, 8.2
2, 2.3, 8.1
4, 4.6, 9.2
```

I want the output looks like this:

```
Number, Time, Speed
1, 12, 5.8
2, 11, 6.2
3, 9, 7.0
4, 3, 11.9
1, 6, 9.5
2, 0, 0
3, 7.5, 8.2
4, 4.2, 8.2
1, 0, 0
2, 2.3, 8.1
3, 0, 0
4, 4.6, 9.2
```

Insert rows that are missing.

I know if the number is not repeated, the vba code like following may work. But my data is repeated series. Can anyone help?

```
Sub InsertRows()
Dim x As Long, y As Long
For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    y = Range("A" & x) - Range("A" & x - 1)
    If y > 1 Then Range("A" & x).Resize(y - 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @fishboen, where does the missing data come from? And do you want python code..

Comment: .@fishbone  why cant you just rewrite the cvs file vs your method?

Comment: Is there no series indicator? Category, Type, Group? Or do you identify series by the order in data?

Comment: python or vba is ok. the number is repeated in a series but sometimes if there is no data for the number row, it will omit. But I need to add those missing data rows back to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a new dataframe called data2 with the rows inserted. The fourth row in your sample has an extra variable so i have an extra column added also.

```
data = pd.read_csv("soqn.csv")
data2 = data.copy()
data2_index = 0

for index , row in data.iterrows():
    #Set the current value of the number and the next value in the list

    current_value = data['Number'][index]
    next_value = data['Number'][min(max(0,index + 1),data['Number'].size-1)]

    #Write in the value as per normal if the following value is the same

    if current_value + 1 == next_value or current_value == next_value + 3 or index == 0 :
        data2.loc[data2_index] = data.loc[index]
        data2_index = data2_index + 1
    else:

        #Otherwise, add in new rows till we get to the value in the next row in the original df
        if next_value < current_value:
            current_value = 0
        target_value = next_value - 1 
        data2.loc[data2_index] = data.loc[index]
        data2_index = data2_index + 1
        for x in range(current_value+1,target_value+1):
            data2.loc[data2_index] = [x,0,0,0]
            data2_index = data2_index + 1
```

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsWdY.jpg)

[image]

[New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv1VT.jpg)

[image]

Comment: @fishbone This guy has put quite a bit of effort into this answer for a question that was non-trivial, you should accept the answer and not be so mean spirited.